# Is it possible to use a instanced pojo to insert with a JDBC template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Spring has the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to pull from SQL on a select and map to a POJO object without having to make a custom row mapper.  I'm hoping for the same but for an insert statement.  But I'm unable to find an equivalent.

```
public boolean addRenewalQuote(Quote quote) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO Customers (internal_order_number, b_email, s_email, b_firstname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

    if(getTemplate().update(sql, quote) > 0) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The quote string names match the columns in the DB already.  The actual insert is quite large and I'm hoping there is a faster method than grabbing each quote getter individually and passing it to the update method.

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` has not, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` on the other hand has you can use the `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource`. You have to use named parameters to make it work but saves you calling the getters.

Comment: Its close.  I could make a convenience method to convert the object to a map that would fit the bill.  Then use reflection to convert the variable types to the corresponding sql types.  But I was hoping for something that had all the mappings already in place.

Comment: There is but that is called ORM ;).

Comment: @M.Deinum  Then wha'ts the point in calling  spring jdbc as a framework... Isn't framework supposed to provide such trivial feature?

Comment: its almost end of 2020.. Still I have the same question and issue. Wondering what improvents are done in spring jdbc framework all these years

Comment: None. As this is a wrapper over JDBC and as JDBC doesn't support this neither does Spring JDBC. You can try Spring Data JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, but you will have to access the pojo's member variables like this:

```
Object[] args = new Object[] {quote.getOrderNumber(), quote.getBEmail(), quote.getSEmail(), quote.getFirstName()};
int[] types = new int[] {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
getTemplate().update(sql, args, types};
```

Don't forget to change the args array and types array accordingly.

Also, you can read more into the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update).

Comment: While this is a valid approach its very manual in nature.  I'm hoping to feed my object into a method and have it handle all the name and type mapping automatically based on whats defined in the object.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible with JdbcTemplate. You can, in your POJO classes, set up an object.getArgumentArray() function and an object.getTypeArray() function to make it reusable throughout your application.

Comment: @Lockless  This approach you suggested is very hectic as Lockless pointed out... Since the question is asked in 2014..  now its 2020... still the same issue.. what's the point of using spring jdbc then?