# Spring jdbctemplate insert using pojo object

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

My question is exactly asked below 6 years back.

[Is it possible to use a instanced pojo to insert with a JDBC template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043241/is-it-possible-to-use-a-instanced-pojo-to-insert-with-a-jdbc-template)

Its 2020 end almost and I have the same issue.  I have a insert query with too many columns and I have a POJO  representing the fields that matches the DB column names.   Now , I would like to find a easier way to insert using Spring JdbcTemplate.

Query:   `insert into employee(col1 , col2,col3...col50) values(....)`

I have a List of Employee POJO objects that should be inserted.

I would like to do something like this.

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery , employeePojo);
```

I know the above is not possible using jdbctemplate.  is there any other easier approach to insert using jdbctemplate?

Comment: Inserting with JbdcTemplate updates the whole object in database so I don't understand the matter about the number of columns...

Comment: okay..for the sake of simplicity.. please assume the whole object. I am editing the question.   Let's take it as the whole object.. is there any way?

Comment: Yes, JbdcTemplate is designed for that. Does your pojo have an identifier ? Do you use JPA or you prefer a sample without it ?

Comment: I understand currently i.e till date 2020 November , Spring jdbcTemplate doesn't allow us to insert a  pojo into a table  unlike  we have beanpropertyrowmapper for select query which will automatically map all columns to pojo variables.

Comment: What's the problem about making a rowMapper ?

Comment: So if suppose, I have 50 tables and each table has 200+ columns,  you expect me to create row mapper for each table?

Comment: If Your 50 tables have unique structure : yes. But if they all seems the same : You can make clever factory rowmapper using reflexion to factorize common behaviours..

Comment: JdbcTemplate with Spring JDBC module would not be right fit in this case, we need to implement custom object mapping and Java types to jdbc types mappings. Instead Spring Data JDBC might be the right choice. You can save objects and can use JdbcTemplate for custom queries.